# using label as source for calcule swift

Tags: swift

In Obj C I used to use some code for pick up data from label, pull it in float and doing any calcul needed.

```
float chiffre1 = [[label1 text] floatValue];
float chiffre2 = [[label2 text] floatValue];
```

float number1 = chiffre1 + chiffre2;

Now in Swift I try to do the same thing but always end up with error. the code work very well in play ground, but when I use it in my app, and try to use data from a UILabel, doesn't work anymore.

```
@IBOutlet weak var DegreeLat1: UILabel!
@IBoutlet etc...

let deglat1 = DegreeLat1.text

let number2 = MinutLat1.text?.toInt()

let minlat1 = number2! / 60

let etc....

let lat1 = (degrelat1 + minlat1 + seclat1) * pi /180 // error "could not find an overload for "*" that accepts the supplied argument

let long1 = (etc...) * pi / 180
```

I tried many thing check almost everywhere can't find what I do wrong.

Comment: What is pi? You should be using `M_PI`.

Comment: Take a closer look at the types you are using when calculating lat1. They all should be Double, but deglat1 is a String, minlat1 likely an Int...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do but some things I found that looks wrong, you should include the errors you are finding to make it easier to help you.

```
let deglat1 = (DegreeLat1.text? as NSString).floatValue
let number2 = MinutLat1.text?.toInt()
let minlat1 = number2! / 60
let lat1 = (degrelat1 + minlat1 + seclat1) * M_PI / 180
```

I hope that help!

Comment: Thank you I didn't know for the M_PI. Yes I forgot to show pi was = at 3.141592654. I did put the error In the code boxe, who was "// error "could not find an overload for "*" that accepts the supplied argument". I just tried to write the the way you did but it give me more error. "error, String? is not convertible to 'NSString'

Comment: Sorry I am confuse do you still have the error? If so do you wanna update the question with the new code so we can help you.

Comment: I did put the error you just didn't look correctly.

Comment: Your code show "let deglat1 = DegreeLat1.text" you did not fix the code

Comment: I was just trying to answer to my question, because I managed with your help to fix the problem. But a message said this post is close and I can not send what I did for make my code to work. I have to find the way to re-open the post.

Comment: You should be able to click in edit just below your post, don't change what is already there just add a edit section in the end

Comment: I am glad to help as I can, I already create a new place for you to post your new code